# HTML CSS how to align two divs one by one and dynamically change width

Tags: html, css

I have one html form, and need to get read and blue circle one by one (vertically alligned), and when value inside circle is entered i need to dynamically with css change width to get desired value..i try with display: inline-table and block but it is not working...here is picture that of what i get and what i need to get:

```
http://imgur.com/Jt1nuh3
```

From image i need to automatically change left and width on red and blue circle that is depending on entered circle value (+999) and need to bi inline like in down picture...i get using inline for css like in first page...

Here is my html code:

```
<!-- page device statistics -->
    <div class="devicestat" title="Online: 0">
        <!-- page device title -->
        <div class="stat-name">
            <div class="stat-name-devices">Devices</div> 
            <!-- android device -->
            <div class="stat-badget-android" title="Android">+0</div>
            <!-- enigma device -->
            <div class="stat-badget-enigma" title="Enigma">+0</div>

            <div class="stat-number">0</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting the css for the red and blue circles to have float:right; and clear:both; that way they are always set to the right side aligned perfectly regardless of what number they are. Example below:

```
.stat-badget-android{
 float:right;
 clear:both;
}
.stat-badget-enigma{
 float:right;
 clear:both;
}
```

I'll need to see your css and html if you want a better example.